# Is there any system to check that a php script is secure or not?

Tags: php, security

Is there any system to check that a php script is secure or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any system to check that a
>   php script is secure or not?

First, make sure that you have tried your best to make your application as secure as possible. And yes, you could use the famous **[Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner](http://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/cs_joomla.htm)**.

Some of the features include:

- SQL Injection
- Cross site scripting
- Web Security
- Directory Traversal
- Ajax Application Security
- Google Hacking

**Recommedation:**

I would recommend you to implement very famous **[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)** in your projects:

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   malicious code (better known as XSS)
>   with a thoroughly audited, secure yet
>   permissive whitelist, it will also
>   make sure your documents are standards
>   compliant, something only achievable
>   with a comprehensive knowledge of
>   W3C's specifications. Tired of using
>   BBCode due to the current landscape of
>   deficient or insecure HTML filters?
>   Have a WYSIWYG editor but never been
>   able to use it? Looking for
>   high-quality, standards-compliant,
>   open-source components for that
>   application you're building? HTML
>   Purifier is for you!

Comment: +1 for HTML Purifier! Even if that's not for checking PHP code. It's definitely an awesome tool for HTML, and a great aid in filtering XSS.

Answer (score 3):

[Code review](https://www.owasp.org/images/2/2e/OWASP_Code_Review_Guide-V1_1.pdf).

You can catch a bunch of things by having complex coding standards and using tools like [php Code Sniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer) / comparable (e.g. making sure that SQL queries are always parametrised), or using other tools (e.g. what [Sarfraz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681201/check-system-security/2681207#2681207) suggested, or writing unit tests with [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/) that check your code for vulnerabilities), but there are almost no situations where reviewing your code would be optional. (I can't think of one off-hand, but that's not to say they don't exist.)